# django filter by datetime on a range of dates

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model with field "created_at", and I have a list of dates. So, I want to get all the models that are created in the date range.  How ?

I know that we can compare datetime and date easily using:

```
queryset.filter(created_at__startswith=date)
```

But, I have a range of dates, so how ?
Let me know for more information.

Answer (score 28):

You can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup. Just find the lowest and greater date and then apply it as:

```
queryset.filter(created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: end_date is not inclusive according to the doc. Filtering a DateTimeField with dates won’t include items on the last day, because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”. If pub_date was a DateTimeField, the above expression would be turned into this SQL:

Answer (score 12):

You can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) e.g.

```
import datetime

first_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
last_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
queryset.filter(created_at__range=(first_date, last_date))
```

Comment: I have "created_at" as DateTimeField and I want to query model by yesterday 10.00 am to today 10.00 . How can I achieve this ? I tried you solution but its not working.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `__gte` (greater than or equal) and `__lte` (less than or equal). For example:

```
queryset.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.date.today())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) and [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) field lookups:

```
queryset.filter(created_at__date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

queryset.filter(created_at__range=(start_date, end_date)) this will lead to problem which is the end date will be exlusive let take example how will the sql will look to this query as `created_at >= "start_date 00:00:00" AND created_at <= "end_date 00:00:00"` so the best solution is to add max time in date to the end date which is "23:59:59" so it will `created_at >= "start_date 00:00:00" AND created_at <= "end_date 23:59:59"`so you can a achieve this by doing

```
import datetime
queryset.filter(created_at__range=(
    datetime.datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.time.min),
    datetime.datetime.combine(end_date, datetime.time.max),
))
```

also if adding 1 to end date this will be wrong approach because the end date will be end_date+1 00:00:00 so the query will include also the end_date+1 00:00:00 which is wrong

there is another answer for this we can change the datetimefield to datefield

```
queryset.annotate(Date = Cast('created_at', DateField())).filter(Date__range=(start_date,end_date))
```

and there is another answers you play around with it like

```
queryset.filter(Q(created_at__range=(start_date,end_date)) | Q(created_at__icontains=end_date) )
```

OR

```
queryset.filter(Q(created_at__range=(start_date,end_date)) | Q(created_at__startswith=end_date) )
```

Answer (score -3):

Use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter/ to use date range filter.