# Fetch all last two days objects according to uploaded date

Tags: python, django, datetime

In my model News I have:

```
NewsId
NewsSummary
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

I want to fetch all last two days news according to uploaded date.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example how to do that;

#### 1.  Using module [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

orders = News.objects.filter(date__range=[yesterday, today])
```

#### 2. Using django [`timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)

```
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now()
yesterday = today - timezone.timedelta(days=1)

orders = News.objects.filter(date__range=[yesterday, today])
```

Comment: this gives me today and yesterday..I want all last two days news according to the date it was uploaded

Comment: Suppose if I have dates 11,12,13,14 then according to it last two days are 14,13
So I want to fetch all news of these two days..
How to implement this?

Comment: you can using `date__range=[start_date, end_date]` like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379584/6396981, just change the `start_date` and `end_date` with your logic program.