# Proper datetime/timezone handling in Django/DRF

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework, timezone

I'm trying to make a proper date handling setup for my web app. I have a model that looks something like this

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

User can send a request to my DRF endpoint `/api/v1/entity/` to get a list of such entities. Now there is a requirement that user should be able to request all `Entity` objects for a single day, which is determined by the date parameter. Dates are stored in UTC in the database while users of this app are not in a UTC timezone.

User can create an entity with the following date `2018-06-19T01:00:00+02:00`, which is stored as `2018-06-18T23:00:00Z` in the database. Now if I try to list all entities user has created for `2018-06-19` nothing's returned, but filtering by `2018-06-18` returns one entry.

This is the code setup I'm using:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/entity/?date=2018-06-18`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    entities = Entity.objects.filter(owner=user)
    date = self.request.query_params.get('date')
    if date:
        entities = entities.filter(date__date=date)
    return entities
```

So in this case the appropriate date range would be `2018-06-18T23:00:00Z` - `2018-06-19T23:00:00Z`. What's the correct approach to fetch all entities for a single day (or a date range) in user's timezone?

Comment: did you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379589/8283848)

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Thanks, but the solution you've linked is basically the next step I'll need to do. Before I can use a range lookup, I need to somehow construct that range relative to user's timezone though, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhIf I understood correctly, You have to convert the local **`DateTime`** to equivalent **`UTC`** time and query to the DB. So I defined a simple timeconversion function below

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
def convert_to_UTC(local_tz,dt_1,dt_2):
    """
    local_tz : any possible timezone which supports pytz lib (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones)
    dt_1 and dt_2 : local datetime in string in this format ->> '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

    return a list as ->> [utc_equivalent_of_dt_1_in_string,utc_equivalent_of_dt_2_in_string]
    """
    format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    pytz_local_tz = pytz.timezone(local_time_zone)
    dt_obj_from_date_time = datetime.strptime(dt_1,format)
    dt_obj_to_date_time = datetime.strptime(dt_2,format)
    return [pytz_local_tz.localize(dt_obj_from_date_time).astimezone(tz=pytz.utc).strftime(format),
            pytz_local_tz.localize(dt_obj_to_date_time).astimezone(tz=pytz.utc).strftime(format)]
```

To utilize this fuction, change your `get_queryset()` method as below,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    entities = Entity.objects.filter(owner=user)
    date_from = self.request.query_params.get('date_from')
    date_to = self.request.query_params.get('date_to')

    if date_from and date_to:
        entities = entities.filter(date__range=convert_to_UTC('Asia/Kolkata', date_from, date_to))
    return entities
```

hence the url will be like, `/api/v1/entity/?date_from=2018-06-18T23:00:00&date_to=2018-06-19T23:00:00`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `'Asia/Kolkata'` - is there a way to get user's local timezone dynamically or should I just design my APIs around sending this information? Are there any best practices? I don't want the client application to do any calculations on start and end dates, so in the end it should probably work like this: `/api/v1/entity/?date=2018-06-18&tz=+02:00`.

Comment: As far as I knew, you have to detect the `timezone` from the client (angular/react etc).

Comment: In my opinion, If you could detect the timezone from the client and do the timezone conversion, that's the better thing

Answer (score 0):

```
# simplified functions

def localize(usertimzone, date, type):
    """
    type = 'date', 'time', 'datetime'
    """
    from dateutil import parser
    date = parser.parse(date)
    if not date.tzinfo:
        # "if the POST request like `2018-06-19T01:00:00`"
        usertimzone = pytz.timezone(usertimzone)
        date = usertimzone.localize(date)

    # "if the POST request like `2018-06-19T01:00:00+02:00`" then just do this
    utc_date = date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    return utc_date
```

```
#usages example
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        alert_date = request.data.get('alert_date')
        if alert_date:
            request.data['alert_date'] = localize(request.user.timezone, alert_date, 'datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of it this way: any **timestamp with timezone info is really absolute** value, as it can be translated to any other timezone, while **timestamp without timezone is relative** and is reliable only in context of single timezone across the system.

According to above thoughts, you should

1. **Determine required period boundaries from client's (app) perspective** (`start` and `end`, not only date). For example, if app is running in timezone +03:00 and we want entities for 2023-04-01, then boundaries would be:

   ```
   {
       "start": "2023-04-01T00:00:00.000000+03:00",
       "end": "2023-04-01T23:59:59.999999+03:00"
   }
   ```
2. **Convert it to UTC** (*not necessary, though: this can be done in backend or even you can push datetime values to ORM/database as is, they just should contain timezone info*) and **use it as query parameters**.

   ```
   {
       "start": "2023-03-31T21:00:00.000000Z",
       "end": "2023-04-01T20:59:59.999999Z"
   }
   ```